# JavaFX GridPane ColumnConstraints percent width query

Tags: java, javafx, resize, gridpane

So if I have a GridPane in JavaFX and wish one column to use a higher percentage of width compared with two other columns, I could for example set col1 to be 50%, col2 and col3 to be 25%. This works fine, however, I don't want col2 and col3 to have so much spacing between them. I reduce them to say 15% each but then col1 would have to be set to 70% to add up to 100. Neither of these two approaches achieve the look I want, considering resizing as well.

What I have found is that I can set col1 to 40%, col2 and col3 to 15%, i.e. in total they add up to 70%, but not 100% - so what happens with the remaining 30%? From showing grid lines, it appears that the remaining 30% of space gets shared each side, i.e. 15% on each side.

I'm happy with this as a result but just wanted to check if this is how it should behave and whether it is 'correct' and legitimate to use the percentWidth of ColumnConstraints in this way, i.e. not having every column add up to 100%?

I can find documentation in the API that describes the behaviour when they go over 100% but not when they do not add up to it.